# Get-WinEvent used to export .evt file. But can't open the evt file in Event Viewer - File corrupted message

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-2.0, event-log

I have made a Powershell script to extract the Application & System logs from remote servers in different domain. Script works perfectly! However, I am having issues with the exported file. When I try to open the log file in event viewer, I get a message saying that the **log file is corrupted and unreadable**. Below is a part of the script:

```
$apppath = "\\server01\D$\temp\Automated_Logs\applog_" + $server + ".evtx"
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ logname = 'Application'; StartTime = $start; EndTime = $end } -ComputerName $server -Credential $c | Out-File -FilePath $apppath
```

Server OS: Windows Server 2003/2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-WinEvent` reads event logs and .evt files into memory as .NET objects, you can't save those objects as valid .evtx files. 
Have a look at wevtutil.exe to write log entries to .evtx files:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it the PowerShell way, you can use the WMI **BackupEventlog** method.

For example:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTEventlogFile | Where-Object LogfileName -EQ 'System').BackupEventlog('C:\Temp\System.evtx')
```